# Why are elliptic curves constructed using prime fields and not composite fields?

Tags: elliptic-curves, prime-numbers, finite-field, group-theory

I come across this:

> Numbers mod composite number does not form a field rather it forms a ring

and

> every number has a multiplicative inverse under integer mod prime

Maybe these are the reasons why prime field is preferred? By the first above fact it means that construction of a composite field is not possible. But I have seen some research articles about multiplication algorithm using composite fields…

Why are elliptic curves constructed using prime fields and not composite fields?

Comment: By a "composite field", you mean something like $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ with $n$ composite? (Those are *not* fields!)

Comment: define composite field. From what you wrote it seems that (as yyyyyyy noticed) that by composite field you mean something like Z_n with n composite. Elliptic curves can be defined over a field (finite,p-adic,Q,R,C).

Comment: Exactly i mean the same @111

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a prime $p$ and an integer $n\geq1$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ is a field if and only if $n=1$. There are fields with $p^n$ elements, usually denoted $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ or $\operatorname{GF}(p^n)$, but they are constructed differently. For $n\ge2$, they are commonly called *extension fields* (as opposed to *prime fields* for $n=1$), as they can be viewed as extensions of $\mathbb{F}_p$.

There are examples of elliptic curves over extension fields. For example, every cryptographically secure curve in characteristic two is defined over a field of the form $\mathbb{F}_{2^m}$, i.e. a field with $2^m$ elements. There is also the [Four$\mathbb{Q}$](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/565.pdf) curve, which is defined over $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$ where $p=2^{127}-1$.

Doing things over extension fields can get a bit more tricky. There are attacks which can exploit the fact that $n\ge2$, which lead to faster algorithms for the discrete logarithm problem, on which elliptic-curve crypto is built. This gets complex pretty quickly, but some of it is explained in [Galbraith's book](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~sgal018/crypto-book/ch15.pdf) (see $\S15.7$ and $\S15.8$). These attacks do not apply to every curve over an extension field, but show that you'll have to be more careful.

Comment: For the uninitiated: If you have some $x\in \mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ (ie "Numbers mod n") with $\gcd(x,n)>1$ and $x<n$ then $x$ [doesn't have an inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/901472/262906) which violates one of the axioms ("basic requirements") for fields.

Comment: @SEJPM Thanks for the addition! I would even say it violates *the* axiom for fields, in the sense that a ring is (by definition) a field if and only if every non-zero element has an inverse. And $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a ring for every $n$.

Comment: @CurveEnthusiast  Please consider "extension field" for "composite" that an elliptic curve is defined over.

Comment: @VadymFedyukovych You are right that it is better to use the correct terminology. I tried not to confuse the questioner too much by introducing new terms, but have now edited it anyway.

Answer (score 7):

To complete the other answer, one can note that elliptic curves over the $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ ring for non-prime  $n$ are at the heart of [Lenstra  elliptic curve factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra_elliptic_curve_factorization), so such elliptic curves are not totally useless. However, this is not really a counterexample, since the algorithm works by looking for points of the curves which cannot be added, showing that this elliptic curve is not a group. It is not a group because $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a field if $n$ is not prime, and actually these points give a nontrivial factorization of $n$.

If you want your elliptic curve to define a group, you need to define it over a a field. When defined over a ring which is not a field, like $ℤ/nℤ$ for composite $n$, where inverses  do not exist when $\gcd (k,n)\neq1$, an elliptic curve is not a group, and there are some points which cannot even be added. This of course problematic for most applications, but this very failure to define a group can be used to reveal some information on the structure of the ring itself.

Comment: ${\bf Z}/n{\bf Z}$ is a ring but not a group? Is a commutative ring ==> is a group under addition $\mod n$, but not multiplicative group since $n$ is not prime.

Comment: Thanks for spotting the mistake: I meant "not a field". I've corrected it and (hopefully) added clarification