# Why is it necessary that the mod in an elliptic curve is a prime?

Tags: elliptic-curves, modular-arithmetic, elliptic-curve-generation

For the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3+2x+2 mod(23), why is it necessary that 23 is a prime. Why is the elliptic curve y^2 = x^3+2x+2 mod(24) not suitable for elliptic curve cryptography?

Comment: Note: in the linked question the OP thinks that there are composite fields ( that was confusion). See [Frédéric Grosshans's answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43296/18298), not the accepted answer. Also, see  [Elliptic Curves over Rings?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/95408/91106).

Comment: Closed as you didn't respond to the question if the link answered your question sufficiently. If it didn't, please [edit] the question and specify why so we can reopen.

Comment: Elliptic Curves use coordinates in a [field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). Integers under reduction modulo a positive integer $p$ form a (finite) field if and only if $p$ is prime. Note: there are other kinds of fields, including other kinds of finite fields, and the later are sometime used for Elliptic Curve Cryptography.